# react-vr items with fixed position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-360

I'm developing a react vr application. I want to show buttons at the bottom of the page with **fixed position**. that means if the camera rotates, the position of this button does not change.

Comment: Do you want something similar to the "view in vr" button that comes by default?

Comment: You can see my answer to this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859098/how-do-i-keep-some-element-fixed-on-the-screen-in-react-vr

Comment: @Sepehr This seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859098/how-do-i-keep-some-element-fixed-on-the-screen-in-react-vr/53487137#53487137, so I answered there.

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a button with fixed position in react-vr like fullscreen?
let's go to node_module->ovrui->lub->Player->Overlay.js
read code at Overlay.js and create a new button fixed.
remember if you npm install then node_module will reset.